# how to create index in elixir? by using sqlalchemy or what?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I'm using elixir, and I cannot find any index creation method,

and I'm not familiar with sqlalchemy, any examples?

Answer (score 2):

asked this question elsewhere, with this answer:

```
Field(Unicode(10), index=True)
```